# Appearance of numbers

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I have written a code in matlab in which N is the vector N=[25; 50; 100; 200; 400]

The values of E are the following:

```
 E(1)= 0.010572 
 E(2)= 0.002634 
 E(3)= 0.000658 
 E(4)= 0.000164 
 E(5)= 0.000041
```

I want to create a loglog graph of E and N.

To do that I wrote the following code:

```
  axis([min(N) max(N) min(E) max(E)]); 
  loglog(N, E, 'red')
  xlabel('N')
  ylabel('E')
  grid on
```

I get the following output:
[image]

What can I do so that at the N-axis, there appear all the possible values of N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `set(gca,'xtick',N);` after your plot command.

[image: result]

As you can see, this will specify the `xtick`s to be precisely where your `N` data are. You could also *add* these numbers to the automatic ones: for this you should issue

```
ticks=get(gca,'xtick');
set(gca,'xtick',union(ticks,N));
```

Comment: @evinda No problem. What do you exactly mean by that question?

Comment: Given the above graph, which is the relation between E and N? @AndrasDeak

Comment: @evinda, isn't that part of your assignment?:P Here's this: if you accept my answer, I'll tell you:D

Comment: @evinda you should accept the answer anyway :) otherwise, I remove my upvote to your question lol

Comment: I accepted your answer. Will you tell me now? :P @AndrasDeak

Comment: @evinda, a `loglog(N,E)` plot simply plots `ln(E)` vs `ln(N)` (ok, more like `log10` now, but that's irrelevant). If this function is linear (which seems to be the case), then `ln E = a*ln N + c`, from which (through exponentialization) `E=exp(c)*(N^a)`. This means that there is a power-law dependence of `E` on `N`.